# Cannot get any php html email form or wordpress email plugon to work with domain monster

Tags: php, html, email, hosting

I Cannot get any php html email form or wordpress email plugon to work with domain monster.

The email form and/or wordpress plugon's say the message has been sent with no error code but when ever I check my emails I have recieved no such message, not even in the spam folder.

I have tried multiple email addresses in the php configuration but with no joy.

I am paying for the "Business Pro" monthly package.

Is it domain monster or just me?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like phpMail might be turned off.

Try using an SMTP plugin that sends via a real mail server rather than a phpMail call.

Many hosts these days don't support the phpMail function which is used by default in many WordPress plugins.

Just search WP SMTP in your plugins screen. There's loads of them that can help you.